# toggle Class causing problem at the intersecting cells

Tags: jquery

I'm having a little problem with toggle class. If you click 1 and 3, the first `td` cell's highlight will switch from orange to gray. I want to keep the orange color. How can I do this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $('#tb1 td').slice(0, 3).toggleClass('orange');
  });

  $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
    $('#tb1 td').slice(3, 6).toggleClass('orange');
  });

  $('#btn3').on('click', function() {
    $("#tb1 tr:gt(-7):lt(3) td:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('orange');
  });

  $('#btn4').on('click', function() {
    $("#tb1 tr:gt(2):lt(6) td:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('orange');
  });
});

$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background: grey;
}

td.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tb1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><br />

<table id='selector'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn1" class="button" value="1" style="backgroundColor:white" ;/></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn2" class="button" value="2" style="backgroundColor:white" ;/></td>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="btn3" class="button" value="3" style="backgroundColor:white" ;/></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="btn4" class="button" value="4" style="backgroundColor:white" ;/></td>
      </tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sxnk6jwr/13/

Comment: The easy way would be to create and toggle another class, e.g. orange1 (with orange bg ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way should be if you create an own class for each button and toggle them.

I have changed the Fiddle only for 1+3 so you need to change 2 and 4 on your own

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $('#tb1 td').slice(0, 3).toggleClass('orange1');
  });

  $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
    $('#tb1 td').slice(3, 6).toggleClass('orange2');
  });

  $('#btn3').on('click', function() {
    $("#tb1 tr:gt(-7):lt(3) td:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('orange3');
  });

  $('#btn4').on('click', function() {
    $("#tb1 tr:gt(2):lt(6) td:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('orange4');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncopLhbk/

Comment: Thanks, it'd be ok with a few buttons, but it wouldn't look nice when I need to make more than 4 buttons.

Comment: If you want to make it bigger you will need a real data model like a 2 dimensional array which contains the status of each field.

Comment: Thank you, since there's no better alternative, I will use your solution.